# How to print function result, if worked print -- yes, else ERROR

Tags: php, file, csv, error-handling

I am writing a small data entry form. Data gets entered in html form by user & then into csv file on server. Consider the following snippet, that i wrote to do this

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
   $handler = fopen('database.csv','a') or exit("Error: Unable to open file!");
   fputcsv($handler,$_POST);
   fclose($handler);    
}
?>
```

Pretty simple!

The only "fancy" task is display a message to confirm that the entry has been added to the database(Entry added), clearing the form ready for the next entry. Or incase of error, display error message(Doh! Write failed ). I can use **OR** statement but that would only be invoked incase of an error.

Any idea how to do this?

[UPdate]
Thanks for excellent replies everyone! I added conditional statement as everyone suggested

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
$handler = fopen('database.csv','a') or exit("Error: Unable to open file!");
if(fputcsv($handler,$_POST)) {
    echo 'everything okay, add next record';
}
else {
      exit('Error: Record add failed. Try again or contact admin');
}
fclose($handler);
```

}

Comment: Check the return value of the function which success you want to verify. The manual documents the return values of all functions, so that can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
   $handler = fopen('database.csv','a');
   if ($handler === FALSE) {
      exit("Error: Unable to open file!");
   } else {
       fputcsv($handler,$_POST);
       fclose($handler);    
       echo "everything A-ok";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a 3-state switch that:

) does data entry and re-displays the cleared form;

) displays the error and re-populates the form so user can fix it;

) default to no data entry, clear form

Use a post or session variable to specify the action to take, default to no action if the variable is not set or does not validate.